# about the high voltage capacitor found in charger circuit

Tags: capacitor, transformer, charger, voltage

[image]A while ago i have opened an electronic balance charger for a reason to try understanding how the circuit works so I've drawn the entire circuit for that purpose but i no longer have the drawing, but i remember the place of high capacitor voltage in that circuit so i only drew the part where the capacitor is present, to illustrate

and which i would to know is the capacitor role in that circuit, According to what I understood is that capacitor role is Cut down an amount of voltage by acting as closed circuit During capacitor charging,

so my qeustion is that correct? and if is correct i would to know about the others lines connected with capacitor positive line does current will flow to them during capacitor charging a cause of high voltage? because i know in low voltage no current will flow to any line with resistance until capacitor fully charged,
notice : the power source is 220 V
and thank you all for any help.

Comment: I presume the C was low ESR type to improve step current response

Comment: i dont think so

Comment: If, as you say, the power supply is 220V, then the capacitor is under rated. A 220V nominal supply is permitted (in US at least) to vary by 10%. So, consider 242V. But more importantly, that is rms value. You need to find peak, which is 1.414 times greater.  242*1.414= 342.2V . Capacitor needs to be rated above _that_.

Comment: The step response can unbalance cells with mismatched ESR’s during the step, so I think so, the voltage limiters in each cell then must balance the cell voltage after the step.

Comment: "i know in low voltage no current will flow to any line with resistance until capacitor fully charged," That is incorrect.

Comment: If the balancer is applied “hot, it will prevent any diode surge current as the cap then provides this

Comment: i know that the capacitor is underrated (2.2 uf 400 v 50 or 60 hz), but the current will cut fastly from the positive line of the capacitor so the capacitor will work as closed circuit for a very short time, This is what I understood or i am wrong?

Comment: i think i am right, I have never studied electricity, electronics in my life, this is crazy

Comment: _"I have never studied electricity, electronics in my life"_ - then start now! https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_5.html

Answer (score 1):

> And which i would to know is the capacitor role in that circuit, According to what I understood is that capacitor role is Cut down an amount of voltage by acting as closed circuit During capacitor charging,

No. The capacitor will charge to the peak mains voltage and is intended to maintain the DC voltage at a high enough value to allow the switching regulator to work during the low voltage periods of the mains voltage.

> and if is correct i would to know about the others lines connected with capacitor positive line does current will flow to them during capacitor charging a cause of high voltage?

Current will flow of the following circuitry requires it. As drawn no current could flow as there is no return path.

> because i know in low voltage no current will flow to any line with resistance until capacitor fully charged,

Incorrect. Current flow can be calculated by Ohm's law, V = IR or I = V / R. At a lower voltage a lower current will flow.

---

Tip: please learn to punctuate and capitalise your writing properly. Your question required several passess to understand it and I'm not sure that I've understood it correctly.

---